# Castle Windsor register class with constructor parameters

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have the following class:

```
public class DatabaseFactory<C> : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory<C> where C : DbContext, BaseContext, new()
{
    private C dataContext;
    private string connectionString;

    public DatabaseFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public C Get()
    {
        return dataContext ?? (dataContext = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(C), new object[] {connectionString}) as C);
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (dataContext != null)
            dataContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When I try to start the web api, I get the following error:

`Can't create component 'MyApp.DAL.Implementations.DatabaseFactory'1' as it has dependencies to be satisfied. 'MyApp.DAL.Implementations.DatabaseFactory'1' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Parameter 'connectionString' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?`

How do I register it correctly and how do I pass the parameter at runtime?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to register the constructor parameter:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IDatabaseFactory>().ImplementedBy<DatabaseFactory>()
             .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString", connectionString))
    );
```

Comment: connectionString is a variable. How is it passed to the dependencyinstaller class?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Can't you read it from a config file? Do you need to have multiple connection strings?

Comment: The connection strings are retrieved from a separate db and the user selects one of them when logging in. The EF model is always the same but the user a number of different databases to choose from.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Then I would suggest passing it to Get function and removing it from the constructor. It should work with the current functionality.

Answer (score 13):

You can set dependencies on `Resolve()` method by adding an anonymous type with constructor parameter's name

Example:

```
IDatabaseFactory factory = container.Resolve<IDatabaseFactory>
                           (new { connectionString = connectionString });
```