# Initialise a class with a parameterized constructor in the constructor of a Service Class using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Please note that I have changed the code in the question.

Please see the server side code below (WCF Service):

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;


namespace WcfService1
{
    public class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IGreeting, Greeting>(),
                Component.For<IGreetingService, GreetingService>());
        }
    }

    public interface ILanguage
    {
        string SayHello();
    }

    public class Spanish : ILanguage
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hola";
        }
    }

    public interface IGreeting
    {
        string SayHello();
    }

    public class Greeting: IGreeting
    {
        ILanguage Language;

        public Greeting (ILanguage language)
        {
            Language = language;
        }

        public string SayHello()
        {
            return Language.SayHello();
        }
    }

    public interface IGreetingFactory
    {
        IGreeting Create(ILanguage Language);
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGreetingService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string strLanguage);
    }

    public class GreetingService : IGreetingService
    {
        private readonly IGreetingFactory greetingFactory;
        private IGreeting greeting;

        public GreetingService()
        {
        }

        public GreetingService(IGreetingFactory greetingFactory)
        {
            // store the factory until we need it
            this.greetingFactory = greetingFactory;
        }

        public string SayHello (string strLanguage)
        {
            if (strLanguage == "S")
            {
                ILanguage Language = new Spanish();
                Language = new Spanish();
                greeting = new Greeting(Language);
            }
            return greeting.SayHello();
        }

    }
}
```

and the client side code below:

```
ServiceReference1.GreetingServiceClient s1 = new ServiceReference1.GreetingServiceClient();
            string greeting = s1.SayHello("S");
```

`ServiceReference1.GreetingServiceClient` is a service reference.

The code works as I would expect i.e. Castle Windsor allows me to inject a Greeting into the constructor of the service.  However, the Greeting class itself has a parameterized constructor (it requires a Language).  In the code above I have to initialise the Greeting (with a language) in the `Say Hello` method of the service.  How can I initialise the Greeting (with a language) in the constructor of the service?

Comment: Is the `operator` not a keyword (eg: should be `@operator` instead). For the other things, I think I would rather rely on an object that contains the user input and use that reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castle Windsor register class with constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243543/castle-windsor-register-class-with-constructor-parameters)

Comment: @Icepickle, sorry I don't know what you mean.  Could you post an answer?

Comment: @w0051977 duplicate answer clearly shows how to pass constructor parameter to dependency during registration, so solved your problem, not?

Comment: @Icepickle , thanks.  I saw that.  However, in that case the parameter is taken from a config file i.e. it is not passed from a client.

Comment: @Evk, please see my comment above.  Thanks.

Comment: That extra class I was talking about, which handles the interaction with the client, could be containing an "operator" that your calculator function can use at a later time

Comment: @Icepickle, could you post some code to explain?

Comment: @w0051977 See point 1 of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066327/1698557).

Comment: @Patrick Quirk, thanks.  which of your classes is the service.svc? I cannot see how your example uses Castle Windsor.

Comment: @Patrick Quirk, could you explain how your comment answers my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One primary method* of providing run-time, user-driven, or otherwise dynamic dependencies is using [factories](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility.md) to create your objects.  Castle Windsor provides several different facilities to help with this, or you can use the kernel and implement a factory yourself.

Windsor's facility allows you to provide [delegate-based](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-delegate-based.md) factories, which are just methods for creating an object.  You could use that here, but you lose some flexibility in what you can create (if you were to replace the implementation of `ICalculator` to some other class, you'd have to update this method).

For maximum flexibility, you'll want to use Windsor's [interface-based](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md) factories.  With these, you provide a factory's interface and then Windsor will generate an implementation of it automatically.

Let's use a simplified version of your code above as an example.  If you have just have this object:

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    string Operator;

    public Calculator(string operator)
    {
        Operator=operator;
    }
}
```

And you wanted to pass `operator` in when you create the object, you'd define a factory like so:

```
public interface ICalculatorFactory
{
    ICalculator Create(string operator);
}
```

Then you'd register it in your installer:

```
kernel.Register(Component.For<ICalulatorFactory>().AsFactory());
```

Now, anywhere you wanted to use a calculator, you'd inject a factory for it, then just invoke `Create`:

```
public class CalculatorUseExample
{
    private readonly ICalculator addCalculator;
    private readonly ICalculator subCalculator;

    public CalculatorUseExample(ICalculatorFactory calculatorFactory)
    {
        addCalculator = calculatorFactory.Create("+");
        subCalculator = calculatorFactory.Create("-");
    }
}
```

Note that the name of the `operator` parameter matters; by default (you can change this if you want), Windsor matches parameters by name.

If we add your `CalculatorService` class back into the mix, you could use the same pattern:

```
public interface ICalculatorServiceFactory
{
    ICalculatorService Create(string operator);
}

public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
{
    private readonly ICalculator Calculator;

    public CalculatorService(string operator, ICalculatorFactory calculatorFactory)
    {
        Calculator=calculatorFactory.Create(operator);   
    }
}
```

But I don't really like that because why should the service care what the operator is? That's a detail of the calculator.  Instead, change the factory to just accept an `ICalculator` and compose the objects together where you're creating this service:

```
public interface ICalculatorServiceFactory
{
    ICalculatorService Create(ICalculator calculator);
}

public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
{
    private readonly ICalculator Calculator;

    public CalculatorService(ICalculator calculator)
    {
        Calculator=calculator;
    }
}

public class CalculatorServiceUseExample
{
    public CalculatorServiceUseExample(ICalculatorServiceFactory calculatorServiceFactory, ICalculatorFactory calculatorFactory)
    {
        var addCalculator = calculatorFactory.Create("+");
        var service = calculatorServiceFactory.Create(addCalculator);

        // TODO: use the service
    }
}
```

There are advantages and disadvantages to use this pattern, which I go over in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066327/1698557).  Some advantages are that you *can* protect yourself from future changes and avoid service locator patterns.  Disadvantages include a proliferation of interface objects and potentially viral usage of factories (see my first solution above where we had to create another factory).

** There are others of course, this is just the way I'd solve this particular situation because, to me, it indicates intent and is the most discoverable for readers of your code.*

---

Based on your edit regarding WCF and what I understand you're trying to do, I'd implement the service contract like so:

```
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
{
    private readonly ICalculatorFactory calculatorFactory;
    private ICalculator calculator;

    public CalculatorService(ICalculatorFactory calculatorFactory)
    {
        // store the factory until we need it
        this.calculatorFactory = calculatorFactory;
    }

    public void ChangeCalculatorServiceClient(string operator)
    {
        // A new operator, we'll need a new calculator
        calculator = calculatorFactory.Create(operator);
    }
}
```

---

Well, again you've changed your question to include another wrinkle; now you want to instantiate a different type based on a parameter.  You can and should still use a factory for this, and this is how I'd go about it:

```
using Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory;

public class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IGreeting, Greeting>(),
            Component.For<IGreetingFactory>().AsFactory(),
            Component.For<IGreetingService, GreetingService>(),
            Component.For<ILanguageFactory, LanguageFactory>());
    }
}

public interface ILanguageFactory
{
    ILanguage Create(string language);
}

public class LanguageFactory : ILanguageFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public LanguageFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public ILanguage Create(string language)
    {
        switch (language)
        {
            case "S":
                return kernel.Resolve<Spanish>();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

public class GreetingService : IGreetingService
{
    private readonly IGreetingFactory greetingFactory;
    private readonly ILanguageFactory languageFactory;
    private IGreeting greeting;

    public GreetingService(IGreetingFactory greetingFactory, ILanguageFactory languageFactory)
    {
        // store the factory until we need it
        this.greetingFactory = greetingFactory;
    }

    public string SayHello (string strLanguage)
    {
        var language = languageFactory.Create(strLanguage);
        greeting = greetingFactory.Create(language);
        return greeting.SayHello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what would the code on the client side (windows form with a service reference to the WCF) look like? As it stands I cannot see how it passes the operator to the service constructor.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know which of the code is client side, so I can't really say.

Comment: Could you explain how this answers my question? You appear to be initialising the 'Operator' variable in the service.  I am asking how to pass the operator variable from the client i.e. windows forms to the service constructor.  Is this possible? Sorry if i am misunderstanding.

Comment: I still don't know what the client-side code is here.  Your question doesn't mention WCF so this answer was written as a single-process solution.  Could you post an example of what you want the client to be able to do?

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited the question text and I have also added a WCF tag.  Does that help? If it doesn't then I will add more code/explanation.

Comment: Let me see if I understand.  Is `ICalculatorService` your service contract? If so, is `ChangeCalculatorService()` a method and not a constructor (the posted code won't compile and is ambiguous)? If so, you'd prefer its parameter to be `operator` instead of an `ICalculator`?

Comment: I have edited the code again.  There was a typo.  I have changed: ChangeCalculatorService to CalculatorService.  It is the constructor.  ICalculatorService is the service contract.

Comment: I think that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146198/discussion-between-patrick-quirk-and-w0051977).

Comment: Thanks, however I do not understand the answer.  I have posted more thorough code in the question.  Could you take a look?

Comment: I am sorry but your code does not make any sense to me.  Could you clear the entire answer.  Then have two sections to the answer - one called client code (with the client code) and other called server code (with the server code).  Thanks again.

Comment: This is all server-side.  The client-side is as you've shown; you get the service reference from WCF then just call a method.

Comment: Error 1 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration<WcfService1.IGreetingFactory>' does not contain a definition for 'AsFactory' and no extension method 'AsFactory' accepting a first argument of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration<WcfService1.IGreetingFactory>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Read [the link I provided above](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#registering-factories).

Comment: I have done it.  Thanks for your patience.  Just one more thing.  Why is the language object and factory object created in: SayHello() rather than:  GreetingService()?

Comment: Because `SayHello` takes the parameter that you want to base the `ILanguage` off of.  You couldn't put this parameter in the constructor (due to how WCF operates; the service implementation is constructed once), so it has to go here, and thus you have to create the object here.