# WCF Service has a paramterized constructor, which accepts a struct

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Please see the code below:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<ICalculator, Calculator>());
        }
```

Calculator is a struct.  The error I get when opening the .svc is: "Calculator is not a class nor an interface, and those are the only values allowed.".  Is it possible to inject structs using Castle Windsor?

I have spent some time Googling this, however I have not found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look in [source code of Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Windsor-READONLY/blob/8e2b032b5e88e6948eda1a4f0f2fb96bd53bcb78/src/Castle.Windsor/Core/Internal/ComponentServicesUtil.cs#L37).

So, no, you can't. By design of Windsor container.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you take a look at my other Castle Windsor question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44436494/injected-class-has-a-parameterised-constructor-that-relies-on-the-client?noredirect=1#comment75871195_44436494