# .net: pass string parameter in the constructor of an injected object

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, dependency-injection

I'm Looking to connect a **MVC .net app** to a **Mongo database**. So I start by looking the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/driver/connecting/).

To configure the connection, I have to pass a String in the constructor of **MongoClient** class:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://host:27017,host2:27017/?replicaSet=rs0");
```

The problem is that I'm using **Castle Windsor** package to use *dependency injection* and I'm a noob.

The first thing I have done is to register the component in the **Windsor Container**:

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IMongoClient>()
                .ImplementedBy<MongoClient>()
                .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

And I passed it in the **HomeController**:

```
 private IRowan _rowan;
 private IMongoClient _mongoClient;

 public HomeController(IRowan rowan, IMongoClient mongoClient)
 {
      _rowan = rowan;
      _mongoClient = mongoClient;       
 }
```

my problem is, how can I pass the String in the constructor of **MongoClient**?

Comment: I can´t see where you create your instance of `HomeController`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243543/castle-windsor-register-class-with-constructor-parameters does this help?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe same answer as this post, which demonstrate how to inject a connection string that is a dependency. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243543/castle-windsor-register-class-with-constructor-parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castle Windsor register class with constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243543/castle-windsor-register-class-with-constructor-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UsingFactoryMethod` as stated in the [Documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md#using-a-delegate-as-component-factory). It will execute the `Func` on every WebRequest and create your `MongoClient`.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IMongoClient>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(
                () => new MongoClient("mongodb://host:27017,host2:27017/?replicaSet=rs0"))
            .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

Comment: Is better `UsingFactoryMethod` than `DependsOn`?

Comment: @albert It depends^^ If the ConnectionString is the only dependency that needs to be injected in your `MongoClient`, then you can use `UsingFactoryMethod()`. But if the `MongoClient` needs other depencies that are registered in your container, then use `DependsOn()`. I personally would avoid  `DependsOn()`, if i can, because you have not only to give the ConnectionString, you have to specify the name of the parameter too. Thats an additional hardcoded magic string, that could be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this..

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMongoClient>().ImplementedBy<MongoClient>()
             .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString", "mongodb://host:27017,host2:27017/?replicaSet=rs0"))
    );
```

Comment: Why I should  use `DependsOn` and not `UsingFactoryMethod`?

Comment: This may change according to your need.
You can add the parameter to the config file with the same name "connectinString".